# Back Image Button is not Clickable?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I have my layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/screen_background">      

  <ImageButton
android:id="@+id/back_btn"
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="190dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
android:background="@drawable/button_movielist_back"
/>

 <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout01"
                android:layout_marginBottom="55dp">



<ImageView
                  android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="50dp"
                  android:src="@drawable/tone_movies_banner"
                  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                  android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

<HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScroll"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">                    

                    <Button
                                android:id="@+id/actionBtn"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@drawable/button_action_movies"                
                                android:onClick="btnClicker"/>

                        <Button
                                android:id="@+id/comedyBtn"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@drawable/button_comedy_movies"              
                                android:onClick="btnClicker" />

                        <Button
                                android:id="@+id/loveBtn"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@drawable/button_love_movies"                
                                android:onClick="btnClicker" />

            </LinearLayout>
       </HorizontalScrollView>

<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"          
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The BackButton image i am trying to set from the layout is:

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/back_btn"
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="190dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
android:background="@drawable/button_movielist_back"
/>
```

code:

```
// Previous Button
                    ImageButton backBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back_btn);
                    backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {
                             Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Hello!! button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                            //Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SpecificationsActivity.class);
                            //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                            //ShortfilmCategoryviewActivity.this.startActivity(i);

                        }
                    });
```

when i click on backimagebutton ,it is not clickable

I think the problem persist in the layout xml file

Could any one tell me placing of imagebutton is correct from my layout file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your Linear layout is above the imageButton and that's why you can't access the ImageButton.

**EDIT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/screen_background">      



 <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout01"
                android:layout_marginBottom="55dp">



<ImageView
                  android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="50dp"
                  android:src="@drawable/tone_movies_banner"
                  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                  android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

<HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScroll"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">                    

                    <Button
                                android:id="@+id/actionBtn"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@drawable/button_action_movies"                
                                android:onClick="btnClicker"/>

                        <Button
                                android:id="@+id/comedyBtn"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@drawable/button_comedy_movies"              
                                android:onClick="btnClicker" />

                        <Button
                                android:id="@+id/loveBtn"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@drawable/button_love_movies"                
                                android:onClick="btnClicker" />

            </LinearLayout>
       </HorizontalScrollView>

<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"          
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

 <ImageButton
android:id="@+id/back_btn"
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="190dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
android:background="@drawable/button_movielist_back"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes i can tell you if you tell me what type of layout is desired? a sketch or something..

Comment: i want to place big size images on this layout with horizontal scroll

Comment: You can try one thing Place the ImageButton after the Linear Layout(id : linearLayout1) is over..

Comment: I placed it after android:id="@+id/linearLayout01",my imagebutton is not able to visible,I have added image,please check?